# If $J$ is the $n×n$ matrix of all ones, and $A = (l−b)I +bJ$, then $\det(A) = (l − b)^{n−1}(l + (n − 1)b)$

Tags: matrices, induction, determinant

I am stuck on how to prove this by induction.

> Let $J$ be the $n×n$ matrix of all ones, and let $A = (l−b)I +bJ$. Show that $$\det(A) = (l − b)^{n−1}(l + (n − 1)b).$$

I have shown that it holds for $n=2$, and I'm assuming that it holds for the $n=k$ case, $$(l-b)^{k-1}(a+(k-1)b)$$ but I'm having trouble proving that it holds for the $k+1$ case. Please help.

Comment: Zev Chonoles' edit was good for at least two reasons. First, it looked good. Second, the title was explicit. There are already millions of titles like yours on this website.

Answer (score 2):

### **Hint:**

$$A=(l−b)I +bJ=lI+b(J-I)=\begin{pmatrix}l&b&b&...&b\\b&l&b&...&b\\...&...&...&...&...\\...&...&...&...&...\\b&b&b&...&l\end{pmatrix}_{n\times n}$$

Answer (score 2):

I think that it would be better to use $J_n$ for the $n \times n$ matrix of all ones, (and similarly $A_n, I_n$) so it is clear what the dimensions of the matrices are.

Proof by induction on $n$ that $\det(A_n)=(l-b)^n+nb(l-b)^{n-1}$:

When $n=1, 2$, this is easy to verify. We have $\det(A_1)=\det(l)=l=(l-b)^1+b(l-b)^0$ and $\det(A_2)=\det(\begin{array}{ccc} l & b \\ b & l \end{array})=l^2-b^2=(l-b)^2+2b(l-b)$.

Suppose that the statement holds for $n=k$. Consider $$A_{k+1}=(l-b)I_{k+1}+bJ_{k+1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} l & b & b & \ldots & b \\ b & l & b & \ldots & b \\ \ldots & \ldots & \ldots &\ldots &\ldots \\ b & b & b & \ldots & l \end{array}\right)$$

Now subtracting the second row from the first gives 
\begin{align}
\det(A_{k+1})& =\det\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} l & b & b & \ldots & b \\ b & l & b & \ldots & b \\ \ldots & \ldots & \ldots &\ldots &\ldots \\ b & b & b & \ldots & l \end{array}\right) \\
& =\det\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} l-b & b-l & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ b & l & b & \ldots & b \\ \ldots & \ldots & \ldots &\ldots &\ldots \\ b & b & b & \ldots & l \end{array}\right) \\
& =(l-b)\det(A_k)-(b-l)\det\left(\begin{array}{cccccc} b & b & b & b & \ldots & b \\ b & l & b & b & \ldots & b \\ b & b & l & b & \ldots & b \\ \ldots & \ldots & \ldots &\ldots &\ldots & \ldots \\ b & b & b & b & \ldots & l \end{array}\right)
\end{align}

Now taking the matrix in the last line above and subtracting the first row from all other rows gives an upper triangular matrix:

\begin{align}
\det\left(\begin{array}{cccccc} b & b & b & b & \ldots & b \\ b & l & b & b & \ldots & b \\ b & b & l & b & \ldots & b \\ \ldots & \ldots & \ldots &\ldots &\ldots & \ldots \\ b & b & b & b & \ldots & l \end{array}\right) & =\det\left(\begin{array}{cccccc} b & b & b & b & \ldots & b \\ 0 & l-b & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & l-b & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ \ldots & \ldots & \ldots &\ldots &\ldots & \ldots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & l-b \end{array}\right) \\
& =b(l-b)^k
\end{align}

Therefore we have (using the induction hypothesis)

\begin{align}
\det(A_{k+1}) & =(l-b)\det(A_k)-(b-l)(b(l-b)^k) \\
& =(l-b)((l-b)^k+kb(l-b)^{k-1})+(l-b)(b(l-b)^{k-1}) \\
& =(l-b)^{k+1}+(k+1)b(l-b)^k
\end{align}

We are thus done by induction.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have to do this by induction, see Ivan Loh's answer. I'll give an induction-free argument using diagonalization.

The matrix $J$ has rank $1$. Therefore $0$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $n-1$. Hence the remaining eigenvalue is given by the trace: it is $n$. It follows that **$J$ is diagonalizable**. So there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that 
$$
PJP^{-1}=\mbox{diagonal}(n,0,\ldots,0)
$$
whence
$$
PAP^{-1}=(l-b)I_n+bPJP^{-1}=\mbox{diagonal}((l-b)+nb,l-b,\ldots,l-b).
$$
Therefore
$$
\det A=\det PAP^{-1}=((l-b)+nb)(l-b)^{n-1}=(l-b)^n+nb(l-b)^{n-1}.
$$
So you have a typo and your expression should be

> $$
> \det A=(l-b)^{n-1}(l+(n-1)b).
> $$